# Cygwin not displaying Vi editor content over ssh

Tags: cygwin, vi

I am pretty new to Cygwin configuration and would need some help.

I have installed Cygwin successfully on a windows 2019 server and is able to ssh to a centos server.
However, while on the centos server there is nothing displayed when I issue the command “vi test.txt”. It shows a blank screen as I type and save the file with the usual vi commands. When I do a “more test.txt” , it is displaying what I have typed though.

The same happens for existing file when I do a vi, but since I can’t see the content , what I typed has corrupted the file. Would need advice on how to display the vi editor correctly.

I was able to launch vi editor locally on the Cygwin window though (without ssh into remote server, on local machine).

Comment: colormap problem ? What is the value of TERM variable ?

Comment: Where can I check that?

Comment: You can use `echo $TERM`

Comment: it says XTERM .

Comment: Does it work if you set it to `xterm-256color`?  Make sure that you inspect/set your TERM settings on the remote side (Centos).

Comment: both local and remote(server) end shows xterm with the `echo $TERM`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure OpenSSH package is installed with Cygwin.

Source: I am the coworker who helped the original poster figure out the issue irl.

We used the cygwin installer to look through the list of existing packages and noticed that OpenSSH showed as "skip". After installing that package, the issue was resolved.